# Can't access child's parent through has_one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested, has-one

I have a confusing problem here. I have two models, with a has_one relationship.  I have a form that uses fields_for to create the child instance.  However, when I try and access the parent from the child model it only gets a nil.

I've tried to provide a concise and simple example of the issue below:

```
class Parent
  has_one :child
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :child
  attr_accessible :child_attributes
end

class Child
  belongs_to :parent
  validate :parent_is_called_mum

  def parent_is_called_mum
    parent.name.equals?("mum")
  end
end
```

The problem is that the `parent.name.equals?("mum")` returns an error:

```
You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
The error occurred while evaluating nil.name
```

Why is the relationship being returned as nil?

Comment: Off the top of my head, should "parent" be capitalized as "Parent"?

Comment: I think that would be at class level and I want to access the instance of that class that is associated with the child.

Comment: Ah, yes, I think you're right. =)

Comment: How are you creating your child? The controller code could help.

Comment: the child is created using the equivalent of @parent.build_child.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but try with `self.parent.name.equals?("mum")`

self may be implicit, so this might not be your solution.

**EDIT:** In your database, are you sure the column `parent_id` in `childs` table is not null ? If it is, then it's normal that self.parent returns null. Nil I mean.

Comment: it is not set to NOT NULL - does this really make a difference though?

Comment: by the way, i removed the attr_accessible :child_attributes line and it works - wrong syntax?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the attribute **inverse_of** to each side of the association:

on the Parent model:

```
 has_one :child, :inverse_of => :parent
```

on the Child model:

```
 belongs_to :parent, :inverse_of => :child
```

Here, look for "Bi-Directional Relationships":
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

Hope that helps!